# Hibernate lazy initializing outside transaction scope

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a service function which is transactional and returns object with lazy initialized fields. But when I use that field outside of transaction scope it is still fetching it. I am not able to understand how does `@transactional` affects lazy and eager loading. Kindly help.

Comment: Probably you are fetching it on a outer and still open transaction. Or the property you are accesing is loaded (ids for example).

Comment: Most probably the session you have created for the transaction is not closed.

Comment: Yes. If I call currentSession.close() then it works fine. Is there any other possible way of doing this so that i don't have to call close session manually.